# Issue in Jquery.get() : success callback function getting called twice

Tags: jquery

The success callback function is called twice, not able to understand this behavior.

```
$.get("getDetails", {
selCity : $("#selCity")[0].value}, function(data) {
alert("reached here");
$("#myform").html("");
$("#myform").html(data);
initiateDatePicker();
});
```

The following statements are executed twice :

```
alert("reached here");
    $("#myform").html("");
    $("#myform").html(data);
    initiateDatePicker();
```

What is wrong in the above code? Or M I missing out something?

Thanks,
Shikha

Comment: You have extra comma after ".value". why so ? Also what does initiateDatePicker() do

Comment: If you use `console.log` instead of `alert` does it repeat?

Comment: Extra comma was a typo. initiateDatePicker() adds & initializes a calendar component to a div. But it doesn't make a difference, because without that too, the function is getting executed twice.

Comment: @Musa In case of console.log, it does not repeat. Why does it repeat in case of alert() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Musa, the issue was because of alert. Replacing alert by console.log for debugging.